# Python новое случайное значение переменной функции каждый её вызов

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, случайные-числа

Использую в программе библиотеки tkinter и random, при нажатии на кнопку вызывается функция resultat, которая проверяет соответствие введенного в поле text числа и суммы случайных чисел (Программа с случайными математическими заданиями).

Нужно реализовать то, что бы каждый вызов функции эти числа менялись (снова проходили через random) и при этом не ломался алгоритм проверки.
Дело в том, что я использую  `z= x '+' y ; lbl = Label (text=z)` . Мне нужно, что бы я мог видеть эти случайные числа ещё до вызова функции, а после вызова функции проходила проверка, в конце генерировались и выводились новые значения.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

x=random.randint(1,100)
y=random.randint(1,200)

text = Entry(width=10)
btn = Button(text="Клик",command=resultat)

def resultat():
    otvet=int(text.get())
    if otvet==x+y:
        pass
    elif otvet!=x+y:
        pass
```

Comment: Вызывайте radint внутри функции, а не снаружи. Все что снаружи - выполняется один раз при старте программы.

Comment: Дело в том, что я использую
 ` z= x '+' y  ;  lbl = Label (text=z)` .
Мне нужно, что бы я мог видеть эти случайные числа ещё до вызова функции, а после вызова функции проходила проверка, в конце генерировались и выводились новые значения.

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутри функции объявите переменные x и y глобальными, в конце функции запишите в эти переменные новые значения, и обновите текст в label:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()

x=random.randint(1,100)
y=random.randint(1,200)


def resultat():
    global x, y

    otvet=int(text.get())
    if otvet==x+y:
        pass
    else:  # Т.к. условие противоположное, то можно заменить просто на else
        pass

    x=random.randint(1,100)
    y=random.randint(1,200)
    z = x + y
    lbl.config(text=z)


text = Entry(width=10)
text.pack()
btn = Button(text="Клик",command=resultat)
btn.pack()

z = x + y
lbl = Label(text=z)
lbl.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Dob4ig "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10" - ну так надо число ввести число в текстовое поле, потом нажать на кнопку. По поводу остального - нужно все условия внести в сам вопрос, а не выдавать по капле.